# How to inject pojo class in spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a pojo class which i need to inject in component. how to inject pojo object in spring?
For example
**RestClass is under Module(like one microservice).  Pojo Value should be injected here only. service class and pojo is different module.**

```
@Controller
public class RestClass {

 @Autowired
 private ServiceClass serviceClass;
 // How to apply MyConfig pojo object into ServiceClass
 //like MyConfig.Builder().limit(100).build();
 @PostMapping("/business")
 private void callDoBusiness(){
   serviceClass.doBusiness();
 }

}
//// ServiceClass and Pojo class is under one module. Pojo object should not construct here. should be passed from another module

@Service
public class ServiceClass {

 @Autowired
 private MyConfig myConfig;

 public void doBusiness(){
    System.out.println(myConfig.getLimit())
 }

}


@Builder
@Getter
public class MyConfig {

 private int limit;
 .
 .

}
```

Comment: As the simplest way, did you consider creating a `Bean`-annotated method returning a `MyConfig` instance in a `Config`-annotated configuration?

Comment: How the value will be set if @Bean? ServiceClass and Pojo class in one module. and Controller is other module? Where to create @Configuration. Can u help in that?

Comment: Modules do not have anything to that. Again: the upvoted answer is suggesting you the same. Note you can also inject `@Value`-annotated parameters to that method. I can't see the real issue so far.

Answer (score 1):

`@Bean` annotation is used in your case. For example:

Create some configuration file with `@Configuration` annotation. It doesn't matter where you create your `Config` configuration class or how you name it. You can even have multiple `@Configuration` classes across your project.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration

class Config {
  // configure your MyConfig class here as a bean
  @Bean
  public MyConfig myConfig() {
    return MyConfig.Builder().limit(100).build();
  }
}
```

Now you can autowire it wherever you use it as in you example.

Comment: i have edited my question . plz consider ... actually pojo object should be passed from Controller

Comment: @shree if you  need pojo in your controller, then simply autowire it in your `RestClass` like `@Autowire MyConfig myConfig`

Comment: then how the value will be set if i autowired from controller

Comment: That is done by Spring, so you don't have to care about that.

Comment: Whenever your autowire `MyConfig`, you'll get `MyConfig.Builder().limit(100).build()` always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Configuration and @Bean. Something like this

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public PojoClass getBean(){ return new PojoClass();}

}
```

Comment: @shree Just add the dependency of module having (pojo) on module (where you need pojo).

Answer (score 0):

**You can use @Bean**

```
@Configuration
  public class Config {
  @Bean
  public MyConfig MyConfig() {
    return new MyConfig();
  }
}
```